# How to define an increasing sequence of additive values

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

Let's say I have the following sequence:

25, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150

Each time, 25 is added to the previous value.

Now, let's say I have a cumulative version of this:

25, 75, 150, 250

Can I define this using the Fibonacci sequence?

How do I find the nth term, and more importantly, how do I find how many terms I can fit in until it hits a maximum number?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the "cumulative" version of your sequence, the differences between successive terms increases linearly: $75 - 25 = 50$, then $150 - 75 = 75$, then $250-150 = 100$ ... each difference is $25$ greater than the last. This means that the sequence can be fitted by a quadratic.

Let the quadratic be $an^2 + bn + c$. It should give the terms in your sequence, using $n=0,1,2,\, ...$

---

We only have to plug in the first three values of $n$ to get enough information to find the quadratic:

\begin{align}
a(0)^2 + b(0) + c &= 25\\\\
a(1)^2 + b(1) + c &= 75\\\\
a(2)^2 + b(2) + c &=150\\
\end{align}

The first equation tells us that $c=25$. The second and third together can be solved to give $a=25/2$ and $b=75/2$.

---

Therefore, the quadratic we want is 
$$\boxed{\frac{25}{2}n^2 + \frac{75}{2}n + 25\,}$$

---

Just to make sure that we didn't mess anything up, use $n=3$ as a check:

$$\frac{25}{2}(3)^2 + \frac{75}{2}(3) + 25$$

This does equal $250$, as it should.

Answer (score 4):

The original sequence is $a_n=25n$. The “cumulative sequence” is
$$
b_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k=\sum_{k=1}^n 25k=25\sum_{k=1}^n k
=25\frac{n(n+1)}{2}
$$
Example: for $n=4$,
$$
25\frac{4\cdot 5}{2}=250
$$
See [Triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) for the formula.

Now it’s simple to decide what’s the largest integer for which $b_n\le M$, where $M$ is fixed: just solve
$$
25n^2+25n-2M\le 0
$$
which happens for
$$
n\le\frac{\sqrt{625+200M}-25}{50}
$$
solving a simple quadratic inequality.

Comment: Nice, +1. For OP: the last substitution is the closed formula for the [$n^\text{th}$ triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).

Answer (score 2):

> and more importantly, how do I find how many terms I can fit in until
>   it hits a maximum number

The sum of the the sequence is

$S_n=k\cdot \frac{n\cdot (n+1)}{2}\quad |\cdot 2\quad |:k$

$n$ is the number of the terms and $k\in \mathbb N$ is an arbitrary constant.

$\frac{2S_n}k=n\cdot (n+1)$

$\frac{2S_n}k=n^2+n$

*Completing the square*

$\frac{2S_n}k=(n^2+n+\frac14)+\frac14 \quad |-\frac14$

$\frac{2S_n}k-\frac14=(n+0.5)^2 \quad |\sqrt{()}$

We take the positive root only since $n$ is positive.

$\sqrt{\frac{2S_n}k+\frac14}=n+0.5 \quad |-0.5$

$$\boxed{-0.5+\sqrt{\frac{2S_n}k+\frac14}=n}$$

You can say that $S_n$ is the maximum number. If $k=25$ and $S_n=1000$ then you can calculate how many terms you can sum up.

$n\leq -0.5+\sqrt{\frac{2000}{25}+\frac14}=8.45...$

Since n is a whole number you can sum up 8 terms:

$25+50+75+100+125+150+175+200=25\cdot \frac{8\cdot 9}{2}=900$

If you would add the next term ($225$) the sum of the sequence would be greater than $1000$.